# My custom option not working on Right panel on view page

Tags: magento-1.8, php

I am working on a Magento store, the requirement is to move the custom option to right panel.

I already did it,  by moving some lines in catalog.xml file.

```
<reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
                <!--
                <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>default</type><template>review/helper/summary.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>short</type><template>review/helper/summary_short.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>...</type><template>...</template></action>
                -->
                <block type="catalog/product_view_media" name="product.info.media" as="media" template="catalog/product/view/media.phtml"/>
                <block type="core/text_list" name="alert.urls" as="alert_urls" translate="label">
                    <label>Alert Urls</label>
                </block>

                <action method="setTierPriceTemplate"><template>catalog/product/view/tierprices.phtml</template></action>

                <block type="catalog/product_list_upsell" name="product.info.upsell" as="upsell_products" template="catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml">
                    <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>4</columns></action>
                    <action method="setItemLimit"><type>upsell</type><limit>4</limit></action>
                </block>

                <block type="catalog/product_view_additional" name="product.info.additional" as="product_additional_data" />
                <block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.description" as="description" template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml">
                    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                </block>
                <block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml">
                    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                </block>
                <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addto" as="addto" template="catalog/product/view/addto.phtml"/>
                <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.addtocart" as="addtocart" template="catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml"/>

                <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.extrahint" as="extrahint" translate="label">
                    <label>Product View Extra Hint</label>
                </block>                

            </block>
        </reference>
        <reference name="right">
        <!--#####################################################-->
                <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.options.wrapper" as="product_options_wrapper" template="catalog/product/view/options/wrapper.phtml" translate="label">
                    <label>Info Column Options Wrapper</label>
                    <block type="core/template" name="options_js" template="catalog/product/view/options/js.phtml"/>
                    <block type="catalog/product_view_options" name="product.info.options" as="product_options" template="catalog/product/view/options.phtml">
                        <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>text</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_text</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/text.phtml</template></action>
                        <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>file</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_file</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/file.phtml</template></action>
                        <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>select</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_select</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/select.phtml</template></action>
                        <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>date</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_date</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/date.phtml</template></action>
                </block>
                        <block type="core/html_calendar" name="html_calendar" as="html_calendar" template="page/js/calendar.phtml"/>
                    </block>
                <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom" as="product_options_wrapper_bottom" template="catalog/product/view/options/wrapper/bottom.phtml" translate="label">
                    <label>Bottom Block Options Wrapper</label>
                    <action method="insert"><block>product.tierprices</block></action>
                    <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.clone_prices" as="prices" template="catalog/product/view/price_clone.phtml"/>
                    <action method="append"><block>product.info.addtocart</block></action>
                    <action method="append"><block>product.info.addto</block></action>
                </block>

                <block type="core/template_facade" name="product.info.container1" as="container1">
                    <action method="setDataByKey"><key>alias_in_layout</key><value>container1</value></action>
                    <action method="setDataByKeyFromRegistry"><key>options_container</key><key_in_registry>product</key_in_registry></action>
                    <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper</block></action>
                    <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper.bottom</block></action>
                </block>
                <block type="core/template_facade" name="product.info.container2" as="container2">
                    <action method="setDataByKey"><key>alias_in_layout</key><value>container2</value></action>
                    <action method="setDataByKeyFromRegistry"><key>options_container</key><key_in_registry>product</key_in_registry></action>
                    <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper</block></action>
                    <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper.bottom</block></action>
                </block>
                <action method="unsetCallChild"><child>container1</child><call>ifEquals</call><if>0</if><key>alias_in_layout</key><key>options_container</key></action>
                <action method="unsetCallChild"><child>container2</child><call>ifEquals</call><if>0</if><key>alias_in_layout</key><key>options_container</key></action>




        <!--#####################################################-->    



            <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" before="-" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml"/>
        </reference>
```

Now it is on right panel and price change also working fine,

But the problem is that when i am going to submit it by select one

it showing me an error like "`Please specify the product required option(s).`"

this is for unable to take the attribute vale.

```
like size (XL, XXL)
```

If any one know this, please help me 
thank you

Comment: Have you moved the options outside of the `<form />` that get's submitted?

Comment: Why you can use CSS to move right side ?. or it is necessary to do that in layout file. If you have look on the `rwd theme`, product options display on right panel. Correct me if am wrong.

Comment: I am not getting your point, can you please explain me or send me any example to do it?

Answer (score 1):

So I think the reason you are getting this error is because you have now moved the items outside of the form that is used to build the add to cart request. As I see it you have a few options.

1. Change the way that the product page is shown to use a 2 column design without actually using Magento's two column template. This would mean that the form elements would be in the correct place but would cause issues with other items that display in the right column.
2. Leave the items in the right hand side as you have done but add hidden items to the product form and fill these items when you select the product so that the options get passed to the add to cart call.